# Challenge with Not Equal to operator

Tags: sql, hana

I have a problem to solve. I would like to get the countries where the gender not equal to Female from the following table using only the where clause. I don't want to use the sub query like: select country from table where country not in (select country from table where gender='Female')

Any ideas ?

```
ID  Name    Gender  Country
1   Jhon    Male    USA
2   Katie   Female  USA
3   Steave  Male    UK
4   Gerry   Female  UK
5   Brad    Male    AUS
```

Regards,
Chandra.

Comment: What is specifically wrong with a not exists on a sub-query?

Comment: Please provide what you've tried and why it doesn't work. Sub-queries are often a perfectly valid way to do these things.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling this might be a 'test' question, a challenge not to use the normal (and efficient) way of solving this...

Comment: Hi Darnir, Yes. Sub queries are the perfect and valid for these kind of problems. But in my case, I have to use only where clause to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table 
                  where Country = t.Country and 
                        Gender = 'Female'
                  );
```

You can also use `group by` like that :

```
select Country 
from table t
group by Country 
having sum(case when Gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: `"I don't want to use the sub query"` Plus second won't return entire rows.

Comment: Hi Yogesh Sharma, I don't want to use the sub query.

Comment: @chandrashekaralthati. . . That isn't `subquery` only, it is `correlated subquery` which is also efficient method.

Comment: Hi Yogesh Sharma, The group by query doesn't return all the columns. I need all the columns in my output.

Comment: Hi Yogesh Sharma, I can't go with correalted subquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid subquery and get full rows by using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM tab
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         OVER(PARTITION BY Country);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9bd98336d1f995624f53c7cefbcd6a9)**

Comment: It seems HANA doesn't support this syntax: Could not execute 'SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM tab ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN gender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "WITH": line 1 col 14 (at pos 14)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select country
from t
except
select country
from t
where gender = 'Female';
```

As a set operator, `except` removes duplicates.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for this solution. But this solution doesn't work in our case. I would like to achieve it using only where clause. I don't want to use subquery, correlated subquery, Set operations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got your question wrong but why you don't use:

```
SELECT country FROM table WHERE gender NOT IN('Female')
```

Or is it a sub query?

Comment: This query returns All the three countries. But actually we should get only AUS.

Comment: Okay I got your question wrong. So you want only countries with male only?

Comment: Try the solution of lad2025 without "WITH TIES". Works fine for me